# Shopify quantity field not working when outputting multiple collections on the home page

Tags: e-commerce, shopify, liquid

I’m outputting two collections on my home page, with a quantity textbox and add to cart button for each product.

My problem is that the quantity field is not working - no matter what value I enter, only a single product is added to the cart. If I remove the quantity field from one of the collections, the other one starts working, so it’s only a problem when they are both there.

I feel like this should be very simple, but I’ve been banging my head against it for almost a day now, so I am admitting defeat!

Here’s the code from my liquid file (with most html removed for clarity):

```
{% for product in collections.mixr.products %}

    <div class="product">

        {{ product.title }}
        {{ product.price | money }}

        <form action="/cart/add" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="AddToCartForm{{ product.variants.first.id }}">

            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ product.variants.first.id }}" />

            <input min="1" type="number" name="quantity" id="product-quantity-{{ product.variants.first.id }} value="1" />

            <button type="button" name="add">
                {{ 'products.product.add_to_cart' | t }}
            </button>

        </form>

    </div>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Could you please try submitting the form with your dev tools open? Your browser's dev tools should include a "Network" tab where you'll be able to see what information is getting passed to Shopify, which will help troubleshoot where the problem is.

Comment: @DaveB resolved the problem - it turns out there was a problem because I only had one collection in my dev shop, which I was outputting twice to test. That was obviously causing some sort of conflict, because when I created a second collection and outputted that as well, the problem went away. Thanks very much for leading me in the right direction!